# Compare a NSNumber to an int

Tags: objective-c, compare, nsnumber

I've a simple question (I think):
I'm trying to compare a NSNumber with a int, to see if it is 0 or 1. Here is the code:

```
id i = [dictionary objectForKey:@"error"]; //class = NSCFNumber

NSLog(@"%@ == 0 -> %@", i, i == 0);
NSLog(@"%@ == 0 -> %@", i, [i compare:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]);
```

I tried this to methods but I get null as result:

```
2010-10-17 21:57:49.065 Api[15152:a0f] 0 == 0 -> (null)
2010-10-17 21:57:49.065 Api[15152:a0f] 0 == 0 -> (null)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. The result of comparison is a BOOL which is not an Objective-C object. Therefore you should **not** print it using `%@`. Try `%d` instead (shows 0 or 1).
2. `[a compare:b]` returns -1 if `a < b`, 0 if `a == b` and 1 if `a > b`. So your 2nd result is expected.
3. You cannot compare an NSNumber directly with an integer. That `i == 0` is actually a *pointer* comparison which checks whether `i` is NULL (0), which of course is FALSE if that number exists. So the 1st result is also expected.
4. If you want to check for equality, [use `[a isEqualToNumber:b]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/isEqualToNumber%3a). Alternatively, you could extract the integer out with `[a intValue]` and compare with another integer directly.

So the followings should work:

```
NSLog(@"%@ == 0 -> %d", i, [i isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]);
NSLog(@"%@ == 0 -> %d", i, [i intValue] == 0);
```

If the "number" is in fact a boolean, it's better to take the `-boolValue` instead.

```
NSLog(@"%@ == 0 -> %d", i, ! [i boolValue]);
```

Comment: I should remember me to not use %@ :) Thanks ;)

Answer (score 9):

Here you're comparing the pointer of the object i with 0, which I'm afraid is not what you want.

You most probably want to compare the value of i:

```
if ([i intValue]==0) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily write:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];
int integer = 1234;

NSLog(@"%@ == %i : %i", number, integer, [number intValue] == integer);
```

Output should be

```
123 == 1234 : 0
```

I hope i can help you!

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

- You are confusing the NSNumber object with the value it represents.
- Your `NSLog` format string does not match the types of the arguments that you provide.

Regarding the first problem: `i` is an address, perhaps something like `0x1f84b`. When you test whether `i == 0`, you are testing whether `i == NULL`. In this case, that means you are testing whether the key "error" was present in the dictionary or not, since looking up a non-existent key garners a `NULL`.

`[i intValue]`, on the other hand, is an integer. If the `NSNumber` contains a value representable as an integer, this will be the value of the `NSNumber`. That is what you see when you print the `NSNumber`'s description using the `%@` format specifier.

Regarding the second problem: Comparisons in C and Objective-C return an integer, either 0 (meaning false) or 1 (meaning true). In order to directly print the result of a comparison, you thus need to use the integer format specifier. There are actually two such specifiers, `%i` and `%d`. You could wrap the result of the comparison in an NSNumber and use `%@` to print that, but that's more work than it's worth.

So, here's what you should be doing:

```
NSNumber *i = [dictionary objectForKey:@"error"];
BOOL haveValue = (i != NULL);
if (haveValue) {
    int iValue = [i intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d == 0 -> %d", iValue, iValue == 0);
    NSLog(@"%@ compared to 0 -> %d", i, [i compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"*** Dictionary has no value for key \"error\"!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
if (thevariable.intValue==0) {
  ...
}
```